# Edit or export drop down lists in Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, export

Working on an existing spreadsheet which contains two dropdown lists.  Is it possible to export or edit data from these drop lists?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to export the list from a Data Validation list to another sheet?

Comment: No, the xls data is being migrated to a database.

Comment: Oh I see that you have edited your answer below. My answer was based on your answer :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Data Validation list, you can have these 3 scenarios.

**A)** A formula which refers to a range in the same sheet

[image]

**B)** A List which is directly typed using commas

[image]

**C)** A formula which refers to a named range from same/another sheet

[image]

Now we need to cater to all the three scenarios in case we want to retrieve that list.

To access the list of a Data Validation Cell, you have to use the `Rng.Validation.Formula1`

See this code.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dvRng As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strList As String
    Dim MyAr() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dvRng = ws.Range("A1") ' Case A
    'Set dvRng = ws.Range("C1") ' Case B
    'Set dvRng = ws.Range("E1") ' Case C

    '~~> Get the formula in the data validation
    strList = dvRng.Validation.Formula1

    '~~> Check if it has an = sign for Case A and Case C
    If InStr(1, strList, "=") Then
        strList = Replace(strList, "=", "")
        Set rng = Range(strList)
        rng.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
    Else
    '~~> Case B
        If InStr(1, strList, ",") Then
            MyAr = Split(strList, ",")
            Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & UBound(MyAr) + 1).Resize.Value = Application.Transpose(MyAr)
        Else
            Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = strList
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have commented the code so you shouldn't face any problems. Still if you do then simply ask :)

Comment: I just wanted to add that I found that if I try to get Range(MyCell.Validation.Formula1) in the worksheet's Change event, I get an error. Same problem in the worksheet's Calculation event. I found that a workaround is to put that bit in a public function in a standard module, passing the cell reference to it as a parameter, and call that function from the Change event.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better idea, I've selected each of the items into a different cell, then copied that into a csv file where I can import into a table.