# Is there a way to manipulate each item in Data Validation in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a loop function in VBA to select every item in the data validation (22 items) and Copy and Paste on newsheets based on the item name.

I tried Record Macro to see the language from selecting different data validation items but nothing is registering. Is there a way to manipulate each item in Data Validation in VBA?

Comment: To access the list of a Data Validation Cell, you have to use the `Rng.Validation.Formula1`. You may want to see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426939/edit-or-export-drop-down-lists-in-excel)

Comment: There are two ways to setup **DV**.  The first is using a set of worksheet cells; the second is an internal list..................which are you using ??

Comment: Hi @Gary'sStudent, I am using the 2nd form.

Comment: @Zeta  My posted code will handle either form...............

Answer (score 1):

There are **2** forms of DV.  One that uses a list of cells like:

[image]

and the other that uses an internal comma separated list like:

[image]

This code will handle either form:

```
Sub IsDV()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, rng As Range

    s = "NO DV"
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveCell
        s = .Validation.Formula1
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If s = "NO DV" Then
        MsgBox s
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Left(s, 1) = "=" Then
        Set rng = Range(Mid(s, 2))
        For Each r In rng
            MsgBox r.Value
        Next r
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ary = Split(s, ",")
    For Each a In ary
        MsgBox a
    Next a

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

As the picture shows, `Formula1` creates a string.  If that string begins with an **=** sign, then the rest of the string is an `Address`.  So I discard the **=** sign and make a range.  Knowing the range allows me to grab the items

Comment: This is a great start for me and I am adapting the code. Do you know if I can have the code to return each value in the Data Validation in alphabetical order?

Comment: Also, can you explain the logic behind S,1 and Range(Mid(s,2) in your code?

Comment: @Zeta  See my **EDIT#1**