# Get validation dropdown list of items in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, is it possible to get the list of items in a data validation dropdown list?

I can get the formula:

```
MyCell.Validation.Formula1
```

But that isn't very helpful when the formula is something like this:

```
=OFFSET(ServiceTypeStart,MATCH($F13,ServiceTypeEntries,0),1,COUNTIF(ServiceTypeEntries,$F13),1)
```

Or this:

```
=OFFSET(ServiceResourceStart,MATCH($F13&"-"&$G13,ServiceResourceEntries,0),1,COUNTIF(ServiceResourceEntries,$F13&"-"&$G13),1)
```

Any thoughts?

**What I'm really trying to determine is whether the item in the cell matches any of the items in the cell's dropdown list. If I could just get a true/false on that, I'd be good to go.**

The scenario is that there are three dropdowns in three columns. The first one, on the left, always allows choosing any of it's items. The 2nd dropdown limits it's choices to valid choices based on what is chosen in the first one. And the third one limits it's choices to valid choices based on what is chosen in the first two.

All is well until a person goes through all three, then goes back to the first one and chooses something different. Now the items previously chosen in the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns are invalid. The same thing can happen if they go back and choose something different in the 2nd after making a choice in the 3rd, though there are fewer wrong choices available there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426939/edit-or-export-drop-down-lists-in-excel I just tested the code in this post with your formula and it works just fine :) `Set rng = Range(strList)` and then if you do `Debug.Print rng.Address` you will get the relevant cell address

Comment: What? Did you mean that answer for a different question? I'm not looking for the address of anything. I'm looking for a list (array) of items in the dropdown.

Comment: Once you have the range, will you not get what is in that range?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I can easily find what is in the cell itself; that is not the problem. What I'm looking for is the array of items in the cell's data validation dropdown list. Those items are not in the cell itself.

Comment: May be I misunderstood but your DV List is made up of the values which were evaluated by that formula. So when  you say `Set rng = Range(strList)`, it means the `rng` range has all the values which the DV List has.

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean Set rng = Range(MyCell.Validation.Formula1). Yes, that works to return the range of items found in the list! Woo-hoo!

Comment: `Ah, I see, you mean Set rng = Range(MyCell.Validation.Formula1). Yes, that works to return the range of items found in the list! Woo-hoo! – Greg Lovern 6 mins ago` I am happy that I did not misunderstand the question ;) Closing the post as duplicate of that post